# What are the purpose of Soul Remains?

Tags: demons-souls

I've been playing Demon's souls again recently and I'm at Shrine of Storms (4th pillar clockwise). It seems that `Soul Remains` has a high drop rate amongst the Skeleton enemies.

Looking at the description `Attracts those who are hungry for Souls`, chucked a few here and there but can't really seem to ascertain what they do. Are they useful for anything?

Comment: if you get clever with them, you can trick enemies into falling off ledges.

Comment: @ColinD interesting.

Comment: Uh, nice. Good to know ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Demon's Souls Wiki](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/soul-remains): "Diverts demons attention towards the remains, works well in conjunction with Thief's Ring or Cloak". So you can use the Soul Remains to distract attacking enemies. They will be targeting the Soul Remains for a few seconds, afterwards they'll continue attacking you. Soul Remains do work on black phantoms but not on bosses.

Comment: `So you can use the Soul Remains to distract attacking enemies. They will be targeting them for a few seconds and leave you alone.`  Who are you referencing in 'them'

Comment: Apologies for the bad/false wording. I changed the sentence: "So you can use the Soul Remains to distract attacking enemies. They will be targeting the Soul Remains for a few seconds, afterwards they'll continue attacking you."

Comment: Ah, so if I was in a battle with a few enemies. I could throw the `Soul Remains` at one of the enemies and the others would attack it?

Comment: Hm, never tried it but theoretically yes ^^